# "Abort Trap: 6" when attempting OpenCV video capture on macOS Mojave

Tags: c++, macos, opencv

I've tried on both Python on C++, and every time I call cap.open(0), I get an Abort Trap: 6 error. I haven't been able to find any solutions to this via Google, and have tried reinstalling OpenCV several times now. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

iTerm might be messing things up for you. It worked for me when I used the normal terminal.

Comment: This was the issue. I switched to the normal terminal and it worked just fine.

Comment: this worked for me as well but has anyone a clue to why this is?

Answer (score 6):

Most likely your mac blocks the webcam access.
Check 
System Pref -> Security & Privacy -> Privacy -> Camera.
If the app that you try to use is not listed there, opencv produce "Abort trap: 6"

Comment: How to add Code to the list? It is not there and I don't see how to add it too there.

Answer (score 5):

In VSCode:

1. Do cmd+shift+p
2. Enter "shell command: Install code in PATH"
3. Close VS Code
4. Use `sudo code` to open VS Code
5. It will give a warning not to run as a root user
6. Ignore the warning and run the file, and you will not get the "Abort trap: 6" error anymore.

Answer (score 0):

install code in vsstudio code and then open terminal and type code, it will open visual studio code and it will have all the permisions.